# Who wins when the Inquisitor kills somebody in Blood Bound?

Tags: untagged

In the game Blood Bound, the rules for winning are as such:

> The game ends when one player becomes captured, after which 
>   all players flip their character cards faceup to disclose their full 
>   identities. If the active player captured the leader of the rival 
>   clan, the active player and his clan are victorious and win the 
>   game. If the active player captured anyone other than the leader 
>   of the rival clan, the active player and his clan lose; the rival 
>   clan is victorious and wins the game.

However, in the case of an uneven number of players, an inquisitor is included, who wins solo with the following win rules:

> Determine the victorious clan as normal (see “Winning the 
>   Game” on page 5). Now, flip all curse cards faceup. If the 
>   victorious leader has the “True Curse” ability card, the Inquisitor 
>   steals the victory away from that clan, and he alone wins the 
>   game. If any player other than the leader of the victorious clan 
>   has the “True Curse” ability card, the card has no effect. 
>   Additionally, if the Inquisitor becomes captured, he alone wins 
>   the game.

However, the rules are ambiguous on who wins if the Inquisitor is the one to give the final wound to a player, clan leader or otherwise. We had a game where the Inquisitor, identified early and unable to win, decided to ally himself with one of the teams and took out a clan leader on their behalf, theoretically giving the other clan the win. However, as the active player, the Inquisitor has no clan,and thus did not kill the leader of his "rival clan." Who wins in that case? The Inquisitor did not fulfill his win condition, but also the clan leader wasn't taken out by a clan member. Did we all lose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody has met the win condition for their team in the game.

- Blue did not capture the Red leader or capture someone besides the Red leader.
- Red did not capture the Blue leader or capture someone besides the Blue leader.
- Nobody captured the Inquisitor.
- The Inquisitor did not place the True Curse in front of the winning leader (because no winning leader exists).

Nobody wins. Everybody loses. That is the price of outing the Inquisitor early and then giving them the position to end the game as a kingmaker or peasantmaker.

Comment: One could also argue that *this is the price you pay for playing Blood Bound*, but I digress...